# Undefined offset with different numbers

Tags: php

I am trying to explode some links, but some of them contain 7 `/` and some of them have 6 `/`
Therefor I get error `Notice: Undefined Offset 7`, how can I overcome this:

```
$imagethumb = array('6 slashes in url','7 slashes'); // this is just for simulating
$imagethumbs = explode('/', $imagethumb);
$thumbname = $imagethumbs[7];
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Always choose the latest entry in the `array`.

You can count the amount of indexes using the `count()` function.

You code should look like this: `$thumbname = $imagethumbs[count($imagethumbs) - 1];`

Answer (score 0):

Try with `isset` like

```
$thumbname = $imagethumbs[6];
if(isset($imagethumbs[7])) {
    $thumbname = $imagethumbs[7];
}
```

Or even you can try like

```
$thumbname = $imagethumbs[count($imagethumbs)-1];
```